# Extension of a probability measure from the Borel $\sigma$-field of a metric suspace

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

The following might be a simple question in measure theory, though there's something I'm missing.

Let $(X,d)$ denote a complete and separable (Polish) metric space. Let $Y \subset X$ be $d$-dense in $Y$. Denote by $d_{Y \times Y}$ the restriction of the metric $d$ to $Y$, i.e. 
$$
d_{Y \times Y}(y_1,y_2)=d(y_1,y_2)
$$

for all $y_1,y_2 \in Y$. Observe that the subspace $(Y,d_{Y\times Y})$ is separable.

Let $\mathcal{B}_Y$ and $\mathcal{B}_X$ denote the borel $\sigma$-fields generated by the $d_{Y\times Y}$- and $d$-metric topologies on $Y$ and $X$, respectively.

**QUESTION 1** Is it true that $\mathcal{B}_Y \subset \mathcal{B}_X$?

Next, let $P$ be a probability measure on the measure space $(Y, \mathcal{B}_Y)$, with full support (i.e. all the open sets have nonzero mass).

**QUESTION 2** Is there a measure $\tilde{P}$ on the measure space $(X,\mathcal{B}_X)$, such that the following two conditions:

1. $\tilde{P}$ extends $P$ to $\mathcal{B}_X$ and
2. $\tilde{P}$ has support equal to $X$

are satisfied? If so, is $\tilde{P}$ unique?

To have a positive answer to both questions, do we need to ask more about $Y$? (e.g. $Y \in \mathcal{B}_X$)

**ADDENDUM**: In particular, does the fact that $Y$ is dense guarantee $Y \in \mathcal{B}_X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this wasn't answered: In general, if $A \subseteq \Omega$ and $\sigma(\epsilon)$ is the generated sigma algebra on $\Omega$, then $A \cap \sigma(\epsilon) = \sigma(A \cap \epsilon)$ (where the intersection is, of course, pairwise). In particular, if $\Omega$ is Hausdorff, $A$ is given the subspace topology, and $\mathcal B(\Omega), \mathcal B(A) $ represent the Borel algebras on $\Omega, A$ respectively then $\mathcal B(A) = A \cap \mathcal B(\Omega) $. Since induced metrics give the subspace topology and metric spaces are Hausdorff, your first question follows immediately: the algebra on the subset is itself a subset of the ambient algebra if and only if the subset is a Borel set of the ambient space. I believe density alone should not be sufficient; for example, there are dense, non-Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ and these should lead to counter-examples.